# How to make an image clickable in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently, the code chooses images from a folder and displays it on the tkinter window. I can click 'Next image' to see the next image from the folder. I would like to make the images clickable, so that it take would take me to a specified link. I can make it clickable but not sure how to bind the different links to each image. It will get confusing if I were to randomize the images(planning to do this later)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os

img_list = []

def save_to_list(event):
    click_loc = [event.x, event.y]
    print ("you clicked on", click_loc)
    img_list.append(click_loc)

def next_img():
    img_label.img = tk.PhotoImage(file=next(imgs))
    img_label.config(image=img_label.img)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
# Choose multiple images
img_dir = askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="./yoga_Images/", title='Choose folder')
os.chdir(img_dir)
imgs = iter(os.listdir(img_dir))

img_label = tk.Label(root)
img_label.pack()
img_label.bind("<Button-1>",save_to_list)

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Next image', command=next_img)
btn.pack()

next_img()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Whats `img_label.bind("<Button->",save_to_list)` and `<Button->` ?? and i think `img_label.img` should be `img_label.image`

Comment: sorry its <Button->1. Updated the code

Comment: Also note that `tk.PhotoImage(..)` only works with png and gifs mainly otherwise youll have to use `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage`

Comment: All my images are .png

Comment: Weird enough i get `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`  with all the directory in my pc

Comment: @CoolCloud: `img_label.img` and `img_label.image` both work, as would `image_label.anything_else`. The attributre isn't a part of tkinter, it's a custom attribute.

Comment: I believe you need to use `"<Button-1>"`.

Comment: @martineau you're right. 
Any idea how I can make the images clickable?

Comment: What to you mean by "take me to a specified link" and where are they specified? Generally speaking, you can make an image clickable by binding a callback function to the `tk.PhotoImage` widget…and there are simple ways to determine which one is being clicked, so you don't need create a separate callback function for each one. I cannot show you how to do this until I know what kind of information you want to associate with each image (i.e. "link").

Comment: @martineau I just want each image to take me to a url existing on the web. ex: www.google.com, www.youtube.com, etc.

Comment: What defines the url associated with each image — what is the source of that information? Perhaps _that's_ your question…

Comment: Once you have obtained the url corresponding to the image, you can use [`webbrowser.open_new()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open_new) to display it using the default browser..

Comment: @martineau Sorry for any confusion. I want each image to open a different link. Since the images in the folder will be randomly displayed, I'm not sure how I can assign a different url to each image.

Comment: There are a number of possibilities. One would be to hardcode a url for each one in your code in the form of a dictionary literal mapping each image file name to a url (or vise-versa). Instead of hardcoding it, the dictionary data could be stored in a separate "preferences" file which was read at startup. Alternatively, there could be some kind of setup procedure where the information for the table was created interactively (and saved in the aforementioned preferences file).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply specify a image object when creating a button.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

def example():
    print("Clickable Image!")

root = tk.Tk()

image = Image.open("image.png")
btnPhoto= ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

imgBtn = tk.Button(root, image=btnPhoto, command=example)
imgBtn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here is some code if you want to make multiple clickable images, don't forget to specify your image directory (Apologies for using list comprehensions, I know they are somewhat confusing).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import os


def example():
    print("Clickable Image!")


root = tk.Tk()

imgDir = "imgs"
images = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(imgDir, imgName))) for imgName in os.listdir(imgDir)]

for img in images:
    imgBtn = tk.Button(root, image=img, command=example)
    imgBtn.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Glatinis! It works with one image. I want each image in a folder to have its own specified url. Any clue on how to go about it?